# How to get mysql data between SouthWest and NorthEast bounds

Tags: google-maps

Please help me to write mysql query. So that I can get records only for google map visible area.

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var nelat = northEast.lat();
var nelng = northEast.lng();
var swlat = southWest.lat();
var swlng = southWest.lng();
```

I want to load records only for the map visible area. Please find below my mysql query. It works for Asia Pacific and not for Europe and America.

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE latitude BETWEEN '".trim($_GET['swlat'])."' AND '".trim($_GET['nelat'])."' AND longitude BETWEEN '".trim($_GET['nelng'])."' AND '".trim($_GET['swlng'])."'
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the order of your numbers, more specifically, putting the smallest *first*. `BETWEEN` is a stupid operand.

What gave me the clue to this one is the fact that it works in Asia Pacific (positive lat, positive long).